# Can I wrap skin around a frame?

Tags: add-on, meta-objects

I am creating a monster, with a body made of thin skin stretched tightly over a skeletal frame. The skin should look something like this:

[image: cassandra]
<sub>(source: [telegraph.co.uk](http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02739/cassandra_2739206k.jpg))</sub>

One way I thought of to do this is to use meta objects that "attract" to the clamps of the frame, but I don't actually know how to do that. I also thought that perhaps I could a plane of skin-texture, solidify it and wrap it using some kind of physics or constraints.

Is there any add-on or tool to properly wrap skin around a frame?

Comment: This is one of those cases where the best approach may vary depending on what you want it to look like and do. Without seeing a sketch of *your* monster it's hard to guess, but I want to ask - will this be animated? Does the skin need to slide over the frame? First possibilities that come to mind are the Shrinkwrap Modifier, weight painting for the stretch, and rigging the skin to the frame in a way that they move together and interact. Then Solidify, like you mentioned. If your monster is as simple as the reference though, all you need to do is subdivide a plane, stretch, and Solidify.

Comment: It won't be animated, and it won't be sliding around. The actual monster is quite complicated, so just a plane won't work. Shrinkwrap sounds like a good idea, though. Thanks!